# Audit java entities without Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, audit, hibernate-envers

I'm facing a problem. I would like to audit my java entities but i use a custom e-commerce solution that i extend and i can't annoted his default entities with Envers.

Do you know an other project like Envers to achieve a complete audit by using XML configuration or i have to use custom entity listeners ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it would be best to contribute pluggable configuration for Envers :). The config part is quite separate from the rest.

Answer (score 0):

[Audit4j](http://audit4j.org) provides such facility. You can use different configuration options in different environments.